# Pandas dataframe return column header linked to data value for each row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, header, tuples

I am using pandas to read any CSV files and then insert the rows into a database. I will be doing this with SQLAlchemy.

I will not know the header names or size, so it has to be dynamic. Assume the database rules will ensure data validity.

I am trying to map the column header to each data value. See below my current dataframe:

```
  Example 1 Example 2 Example 3 Example 4
        Cat       Dog     Mouse     Horse
        Cow       Ant       Pig  Elephant
```

Here is my desired outputted list:

```
Example 1=Cat, Example 2=Dog, Example 3=Mouse, Example 4=Horse
Example 1=Cow, Example 2=Ant, Example 3=Pig, Example 4=Elephant
```

I have tried using `zip` and `iterrows` with the below code:

```
    for index, data in df.iterrows():
        mylist.append(data.values)

    myzip = zip(columns, mylist)

    for z in myzip:
        print(z)
```

but this is producing one column header per multiple values as seen below:

```
('Example 1', array(['Cat', 'Dog', 'Mouse', 'Horse'], dtype=object))
('Example 2', array(['Cow', 'Ant', 'Pig', 'Elephant'], dtype=object))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as not sure what function I need to use. 
I'm aware of `to_sql` but I need to create an insert statement per row. 
Thanks

Comment: `df.to_dict(orient='records')` will help you. In addition, `SQLAlchemy` support pandas insert.

Comment: Amazing thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@giser_yugang hits the ideal solution. **Pandas** has inbuilt method `DataFrame.to_dict(orient='dict')` which converts the dataframe and returns a dictionary, where the key-value pair can be customized using the parameter `orient`.
'records' amongst the 'orient' gives the kind of result you want.

So your dataframe:

[image: dataframe]

After using:

```
df.to_dict(orient='records')
```

gives:

```
[{'Example 1': 'Cat',
  'Example 2': 'Dog',
  'Example 3': 'Mouse',
  'Example 4': 'Horse'},
 {'Example 1': 'Cow',
  'Example 2': 'Ant',
  'Example 3': 'Pig',
  'Example 4': 'Elephant'}]
```